# Counting total number of records in layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, count

I have a point layer which has millions of points and I would like to know the total number of points in this layer.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro 3?

Usually, I just go to the attribute table and click on `load all` but in this case it returns an error `too many records to show`.

Comment: int(arcpy.management.GetCount('layerName').getOutput(0))

Comment: @Brennan, thank you but I am not a Python user as I use `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Get Count](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) geoprocessing tool.